# Passing extra arguments to scrapy.Request()

Tags: python, scrapy

Actually I want to store all the data(text,hrefs,images) related to specific website to a single folder.In order to do that I need to pass the path for that folder to all different parsing function.So I want to pass this path as extra kwargs in `scrapy.Request()` like this:

`yield scrapy.Request(url=url,dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse,errback = self.errback_function,kwargs={'path': '/path/to_folder'})`

But it gives the error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kwargs'`

How can I pass that path to next function?

Comment: You can use `meta` argument for passing extra arguments. https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects

Comment: yeah,I also thought of this thing.But are you sure this is the right way?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It's only one right way

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For anyone who may need it......

You can pass extra arguments by using `meta` arguments like this...

```
   yield scrapy.Request(url=url,dont_filter=True, 
callback=self.parse,errback = self.errback_function,  meta={'filepath': filepath})
```

**UPDATE:**

> `Request.cb_kwargs` was introduced in version 1.7. Prior to that, using
> Request.meta was recommended for passing information around callbacks.
> After 1.7, Request.cb_kwargs became the preferred way for handling
> user information, leaving Request.meta for communication with
> components like middlewares and extensions.

**So for version >= 1.7 following would work :**

> ```
>    request = scrapy.Request('http://www.example.com/index.html',
>                              callback=self.parse_page2,
>                              cb_kwargs=dict(main_url=response.url))
> ```

you can refer to this documentation: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions

Answer (score 1):

It is an old topic, but for anyone who needs it, to pass an extra parameter you must use
`cb_kwargs`, then call the parameter in the parse method.

You can refer to [this part](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions) of the documentation.